# PHPMailer $mail->From headers not working with gmail

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I'm using the following code to send a mail after a form submission with the PHP mailer class https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer. The mail sends and is received successfully. The only thing that isn't wokring is the following:

```
$mail->From = $email;
```

`$email` is the email that a user will enter on the form (it is set with a `$_POST` variable). I would like the email to appear that it's from the user who filled out the form, so I can hit reply and have it go to their email address.

However, the "from" email address is being set as `$mail->Username`, i.e. the username from the gmail account that the PHPMailer script is sending from.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here, and how do I get the From email header to work?

Also, I am using Gmail to receive the mail-- maybe there's a gmail security setting that won't allow the "From" email to be "faked"???

Thanks!

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['moveName'];

require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'example@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';

$mail->From = $email;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress('me@gmail.com');
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Quote Request';
$mail->Body    = 'hey';

$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Where did you set the variables? can you show them?

Comment: Where do you set $email and $name

Comment: Updated just now! Thanks

Comment: I tried your code with another smtp server != gmail. Works there.

Comment: this is my question too. but i found answer. go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336402/phpmailer-gmail-smtp-not-working-properly/

Comment: @j-man86, Not quite sure have you fiured it out? configure ing gamil doesnt look what you were loking for.. Or by breaking the email address you skips to Repyto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With gmail you have to configure an email address as allowed "$mail->from" first. This FAQ entry explains how to do it: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en

Comment: And about Hotmail ? I have the same problem