# How to set FROM in php mailer using Gmail SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I was trying to set **from** in php mailer (gmail smtp). But in inbox it shows from mygmailaccount@gmail.com. here is my code :

```
        $this->_mail->Username = "mygmailaccount@gmail.com";
        //Password to use for SMTP authentication
        $this->_mail->Password = 'mypassword';
        $this->_mail->From="support@mydomain.com";
        $this->_mail->FromName="Support Team";
        //Set who the message is to be sent from
        $this->_mail->setFrom('support@mydomain.com', 'Support Team',false);
```

But when I receive email in inbox its show from : mygmailaccount@gmail.com
and I want to show from : support@mydomain.com

Can anyone help me to find out what I am missing.

Comment: I think this might be a Gmail restriction. The "From" email address must match the address it's coming from or it is automatically set that way by Google SMTP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer $mail->From headers not working with gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001294/phpmailer-mail-from-headers-not-working-with-gmail)

Answer (score 3):

This is a gmail restriction, though it's not all bad news! In your gmail preferences you can configure aliases for your account, and you can send out using them as your from address. So you can set the from address, but only to a choice from that preset list, not any arbitrary address. This question has been asked on here before.