# Cannot set Custom Sender email using PHPMailer and smtp.gmail.com

Tags: php, email, gmail, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer and smtp.gmail.com to send emails to my users. 
Emails are sent, no problem with that, but on the client side, in the sender email address, there is showing my servers host email address, not my email address that is set with PHPMailer->SetFrom(). I want to set my email address as sender email.
I'm using php 5.4 & PHPMailer 5.2.4
My code is given below :

```
<?php 
    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 


    try {
      $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
      $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
      $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      
      $mail->Port       = 465;                   
      $mail->Username   = "myemail@gmail.com";  
      $mail->Password   = "PASSWORD";

      $mail->AddAddress('receiver@email.com', 'John Doe');
      $mail->SetFrom('myemail@email.com', 'My Name');

      $mail->addReplyTo('myemail@gmail.com', 'My Name');
      $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Subject';

      $mail->MsgHTML('This is the body');
      $mail->Send();
      echo "Message Sent";

    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
      echo $e->errorMessage();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }



?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP and PHPMailer are you using ? And why are you passing true to the constructor ? Please be the maximum specific when you post a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer $mail->From headers not working with gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001294/phpmailer-mail-from-headers-not-working-with-gmail)

Comment: true is for throwing PHPMailer exception if happens.

Comment: Passing `true` to the constructor enables exceptions, and the code has try/catch blocks to match. I suspect the OP is also using an old version of PHPMailer because it's not using the autoloader and does not load the SMTP class, which will fail in all PHPMailer versions from the last couple of years.

Answer (score 1):

This is a gmail limitation - it does not let you set arbitrary from addresses, though you can set fixed aliases in your gmail preferences. This is covered in the PHPMailer documentation. It's also a reasonable restriction - otherwise you're probably forging the from address. You can always set a reply-to address if it's reply routing you're concerned about.

Comment: I will second this. You should be sending emails from the email account you intend for your users to see.